# C# Node Collection using HTMLAgilityPack to Data table

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to scrape data from this site. I am able to obtain the data but now I need add the selected data to a data table. The following is very near complete but it is only returning the last record. I know its something simple but just cant figure it out.  Essentially, the commented out portion for the Console.Writeline portion in the for loop will be the desired results in the datagridview after all said and done.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.sportingcharts.com/nba/defense-vs-position/");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection teams = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='col col-md-3']//tr/td[2]");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection points = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='col col-md-3']//tr/td[3]");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection positions = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='col col-md-3']//span[1]");

        DataTable dvp_dt = new DataTable();
        dvp_dt.Columns.Add("Team", typeof(string));
        dvp_dt.Columns.Add("Points", typeof(string));
        dvp_dt.Columns.Add("Position", typeof(string));

        string[] positions_aux = positions.Where(x => x.InnerText.Length >= 6).Select(y => y.InnerText).ToArray();


        DataRow row = dvp_dt.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < teams.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var aux = i / 30;
            row["Team"] = (teams[i].InnerText);
            row["Points"] = (points[i].InnerText);
            row["Position"] = (positions_aux[aux]);
           // Console.WriteLine(teams[i].InnerText + ' ' + points[i].InnerText + ' ' + positions_aux[aux]);
        }


         dvp_dt.Rows.Add(row);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dvp_dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
for (int i = 0; i < teams.Count - 1; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dvp_dt.NewRow();
    var aux = i / 30;
    row["Team"] = (teams[i].InnerText);
    row["Points"] = (points[i].InnerText);
    row["Position"] = (positions_aux[aux]);
}

dataGridView2.DataSource = null;        
dataGridView2.DataSource = dvp_dt;
```

Comment: This did not work. I see what you were getting ad by have the new row in the loop and clearing the data source then re-applying it, but when I attempt to load run it this way, no values are displaying. It just populates the column headers.

Comment: My changes are correct.  Used the code thousands of times before.  There are no items in the variable team so you are not see anything displayed.

Comment: do i need to add a loop now to get the team,points and position to display in each column after button press?

Comment: No.  Once the data is in the DataTable the DGV will automatically update.

Comment: I guess my final question here is how come 
 row["Team"] = (teams[i].InnerText);
is blank but
 Console.WriteLine(teams[i].InnerText);
displays the output

Comment: I suspect the column width is not wide enough to display data.  Try teams[i].InnerText.Trim()

Comment: ah nm I am an idiot. I didnt add in the datarows to the datatable. jdweng sorry I was missing dvp_dt.Rows.Add(row); in the loop. Thanks so much !